# Can aspnet_compiler see virtual subdirectories?

Tags: asp.net, iis, aspnet-compiler

In IIS, I have a virtual directory for my website, which is on port 87, that points to `sites\MySiteName\`.  There is also a virtual subdirectory within the site that points to `sites\otherSite\otherControls`.

Here is an excerpt from the solution file `websites.sln`, which contains my website:

```
"Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "MySiteName", "http://localhost:87", "{5B52E21D-C089-4DCD-A7CA-8B0B70D43544}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        UseIISExpress = "false"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/LM/W3SVC/2"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\MySiteName\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\Sites\MySiteName\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        SlnRelativePath = "..\..\..\Sites\MySiteName\"
```

This works fine when I am actually visiting the site. When I run msbuild on the project `websites.sln` (which contains my site) it dutifully creates a metaproject and attempts to build.  Everything goes fine until it attempts to build a file that references a control in the virtual subdirectory.

`ASPPARSE: The file '/LM/W3SVC/2/otherControls/control.ascx' does not exist. in \LM\W3SVC\2\file.aspx`

[cognethos suggests](http://blog.cognethos.com/post/285291745/asp-net-pre-compilation) that "The ASP compiler now knows where the root folder is mounted, however since the physical folder is specified, it will only look within that folder and hence not find other virtual folders."

The solution recommended there is to leave out the physical path. When I do that, it no longer seems to be building `MySiteName` but instead gives warnings that clearly come from one of the other sites.

I  tried leaving out both physical and virtual paths and using the MetabasePath instead:

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.MetabasePath = "LM/W3SVC/2"
```

That yields the unpromising error

`C:\BUILD\MySiteName.metaproj : error MSB3462: Either MetabasePath or VirtualPath must be specified.`

It's not particularly clear to me why it doesn't recognize the MetabasePath I've given it.  I tried skipping using msbuild entirely and pointed the `aspnet_compiler` directly at the site, using just the MetabasePath and that yieled the same problem as when I removed the physical path.... it seems to be building one of the other sites.